# What is the best point in the app lifecycle to load the current user if they logged in previously?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to look in my localStorage to see if the CurrentUser's session cookie is there, and if so load the user via an API call and then update the store with the session information so that all the other components can figure out if the user is logged in or not.

Is there some event lifecycle I can hook into to do this in?

I have my redux action that will load the user from the API, I just don't know where to do this.

```
const Root = ({ store }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <div className="application-container">
      <App>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/sign_in" component={SessionsNewView} />
          <Route exact path="/sign_up" component={AccountsNewView} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomeIndexView} />
        </Switch>
      </App>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default Root;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `componentDidMount` will do the trick here

Comment: Yes but which component, I don't want to do it in every component.  I need to fetch the user once.

Comment: Yes I want to add the user to the store.  Just want to know when is the best time and place in my react app.

Comment: I would do it from the where my app is loaded from.